# How can I generate a pairwise probabilities matrix with mean and standard deviation fixed in advance?

Tags: r, function, matrix, probability, pairwise

I need to generate a joint probabilities matrix (80*80) with R such that the mean and the standard deviation of this matrix are fixed in advance. It's a symmetric matrix. The main diagonal elements are interpreted as probabilities p ( A i ) that a binary variable A i equals 1. The off-diagonal elements are the probabilities p ( A i A j ) that both A i and A j are 1. This matrix should respond to the following conditions :

```
0 ≤ p A i ≤ 1

max ( 0 , p A i + p A j − 1 ) ≤ p A i A j ≤ min ( p A i , p A j ) , i ≠ j

p A i + p A j + p A k − p A i A j − p A i A k − p A j A k ≤ 1 , i ≠ j , i ≠ k , j ≠ k
```

These conditions are checked with check.commonprob.

Here is what I have tried

```
# First I need another function to make the matrix symmetric 


makeSymm <- function(m) {
    m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
    return(m)
}



install.packages("bindata")
library (bindata)

# Function to create the joint probabilites matrix:

joint <- function(b, x, y, k) {
    repeat {
        b[lower.tri(b, diag=TRUE)] <- rnorm(k*(k+1)/2, mean=x,sd=y)
        b <- makeSymm(b)
        if (check.commonprob(b)==TRUE) break
    }
    return(b)
}

c <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
c <- joint(c, 0.5, 0.25, 4)
c
              [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
    [1,] 0.3956524 0.3156023 0.3007369 0.2837493
    [2,] 0.3156023 0.4330955 0.2920143 0.4145124
    [3,] 0.3007369 0.2920143 0.7921709 0.3616905
    [4,] 0.2837493 0.4145124 0.3616905 0.4318048
```

The problem is that this function works well for very small matrix (4*4)but if i take (6*6), it takes too long to run so I stop it. I need to generalize this function to 80*80 matrix. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you using the `check.commonprob` function from the `bindata` package [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/bindata/man/check.commonprob.html)? If so, please state this explicitly, as it is not part of the base packages & not everyone here has it installed.

Comment: Thanks. It's done !